# Need to send FIN/ACK

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, onvif

I need the code below to send a FIN/ACK when it has completed communicating with the server. I've used sockets before and you explicitly tell it to close the connection at which point the NIC sends the FIN/ACK. Here I don't have that kind of control and am curious if there is a way to force the FIN/ACK. When I terminate the program a FIN/ACK is sent.

I've tried deconstructing the object that is keeping the TCP connection open but am not confident it working correctly. I've tried putting it on its own thread, and setting it to void.

To run this code in visual studio you will need to add a Server Reference (https://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl) and call it "Onvif_Video_Player."

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Onvif_Video_Player.OnvifDevice;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel;


namespace Onvif_Video_Player
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //Form1 Interactive Objecst 
        string IPAddress;
        String userName;
        string password;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void GetProfiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IPAddress = txtbox_IPAddress.Text;
            userName = TxtBox_UserName.Text;
            password = TxtBox_Password.Text;
            GetOnvifProfiles();
            while (true)
            {
             //Do other stuff 
            }
        }

        private void GetOnvifProfiles()
        {
                UriBuilder deviceUri;
                System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding binding;

                deviceUri = new UriBuilder("Http:/onvif/device_service");

                HttpTransportBindingElement httpTransport = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
                httpTransport.AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Digest;
                deviceUri.Host = IPAddress;
                var messageElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
                messageElement.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, AddressingVersion.None);
                System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding customBinding = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding(messageElement, httpTransport);
                binding = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap12, Encoding.UTF8), httpTransport);
                DeviceClient Onvif_Device = new DeviceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(deviceUri.ToString()));
                OnvifDevice.Service[] service = Onvif_Device.GetServices(false);
                ///////////////////////////Send FIN/ACK//////////////////////////
            }
        }
    }
```

Another thought would be if I could figure out what port this TCP connection was opened on, I could manually construct a string to send a FIN/ACK on that port.

As recommend below, I tried using. Maybe I'm doing it incorrectly: I first moved my function that creates the TCP connection to a public class and had that class inherit from IDisposable.

Class function....

```
namespace Onvif_Video_Player
    {
        public class CustomBindingsAndClients : IDisposable
        {
            void IDisposable.Dispose() 
            {
                int i = 0;
            }
    
            public void GetProfiles(string IP, string IuserName, string password)
            {
                UriBuilder deviceUri = new UriBuilder("Http:/onvif/device_service");
                System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding binding;
                HttpTransportBindingElement httpTransport = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
                httpTransport.AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Digest;
                deviceUri.Host = "192.168.1.65";
                var messageElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
                messageElement.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, AddressingVersion.None);
                System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding customBinding = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding(messageElement, httpTransport);
                binding = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap12, Encoding.UTF8), httpTransport);
                DeviceClient Onvif_Device = new DeviceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(deviceUri.ToString()));
                OnvifDevice.Service[] service = Onvif_Device.GetServices(true);
                binding = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in the main body of the code wrapped the instance in a using statement...

```
        private void GetProfiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IPAddress = txtbox_IPAddress.Text;
        userName = TxtBox_UserName.Text;
        password = TxtBox_Password.Text;
        using (CustomBindingsAndClients TEMP = new CustomBindingsAndClients()) 
        {
            TEMP.GetProfiles(IPAddress, userName, password);
        }
     }
```

Still the TCP connect stayed open until the application was closed.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that was a thing. I tried that and it is yelling at me 
"CS1674: Service[] :Type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'.

I should note: The TCP handshake happens @ when Onvif_Device.GetServices(false) is called. I tried wrapping the Onvif_Device object in "using", and while that did compile and run, it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: You're just talking about "graceful close". The code you provided does not make clear a) why you think you need to operate at the IP level of FIN/ACK, b) what layer of API you are expecting to use to accomplish this, and c) what _specific_ problem you have, never mind is it anything like a [mcve] that would be required for such a question. But see duplicate for info. As a general rule, at the socket level, you want to call `Shutdown()`, at higher API layers, you may need to simply dispose the object or use some mechanism it has to shutdown the connection.

Comment: a) Due to design constraints I only can have a single TCP connection open at one time.

b) this is a minimal amount of reproducible code. You can copy and past this into a new project, add the references as suggested, and the code will execute (provided you hard code in things like IP address). 
c) The other link does not answer my question. I've already viewed that answer before. And this reference does not offer any type of disposal for the object. That is what I am up against.

Comment: The number of connections you can have open at one time has nothing to do with how to gracefully close any given connection. I have no idea why you even bring that up. Your question is incredibly unclear. Your assertion that you've provided an [mcve] demonstrates only that you don't understand what a [mcve] is.

Comment: You say "dispose of the object." Shouldn't the update I made (see everything after "As recommended below") be using dispose? 

I'm sorry if you feel like its vague. But do to the lack of documentation on "DeviceClient" I don't have any additional information to go off of.

Comment: I apologize! I'm not sure, Everything in my original post should contain the body of code needed other than the optional fluff of the fact "GetProfiles_Click" is called by a button using window forms. What do you feel that is missing?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Just open a new project (windows form), added a single button, copied and pasted this in to a new .cs file, added references (as I mentioned above) and you'll be up and running. I just tried it again and worked! Not sure what you think is missing.

Comment: The existing open tcp connection should be reused for consequent requests though, right?

Comment: @Jesse de Wit: You're the first to catch on to this. Short answer, yes! This was my assumption and everything works as you would suggest right up until I need to go and set up RTP. I've removed about a thousand lines of code with different TCP connections that close out and start another utilizing this same object. For ever subsequent call it closes the TCP connection and starts anew. But then when I go to stream video using the c#VLC lib,  RTP requires an RTSP to set up the video stream (using TCP). This never closes out my other TCP connection and attempts to start another TCP connection.